# Nested array validation rules not working on update in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, nested, rules

I have an array like this

```
  "fio" => "John Dou"
  "city" => "1"
  "birthday" => "2022-10-21"
  "email" => "test@gmail.ru"
  "phones" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => "7"
      "number" => "911"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => "10"
      "number" => "112"
    ]
  ]
```

The check for uniqueness works, but when you try to update the current record, it swears for duplication

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'phones.*.number' => 'required|string|max:12|unique:'.Phone::class.',number,phones.*.id';
    ]
}
```

Maybe I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: it looks like you are ignoring all the ids in your array, maybe you should check it inside a loop when trying to update the number

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just looking for an opportunity to make validation standard solutions. I had to implement this task through a closure with a cycle.